# How to take screenshot of a whole webpage from browser in a single image

Tags: browser

In lots of place i saw that people using long screenshot of a full webpage for presentation. I tried with snipping tool but i am not able to take screenshot of whole webpage in a single image. I want to know that how i can take long screenshot from browser like this [image]

Comment: You can use https://usebubbles.com for this. It allows you to capture the entire page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Google Chrome then this answer will be beneficial for you.

Just follow some simple step to take long screenshot of a webpage.

**Step 1:** Click the three dots, point to “More Tools,” then click on “Developer Tools.” Alternatively, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> on Mac to open the Developer Tools pane.

**Step 2:** In the top right corner of the pane, click the three dots icon, then click “Run Command.” Alternatively, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Windows and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Mac.

**Step 3:** In the command line, type “Screenshot,” then click “Capture full-size screenshot” from the list of commands available.

> The image should save automatically, but if you’re prompted to save the screenshot, select a destination on your computer, then click “Save.”

**Note :** This feature is ideal on websites with text-based content opposed to web apps, as it could potentially only capture the viewable screen.

For more descriptive answer [go through this link](https://www.howtogeek.com/423558/how-to-take-full-page-screenshots-in-google-chrome-without-using-an-extension/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Awesome screenshot. It's extension is also easily available for chrome. Just add it to chrome and you will have option to take screenshot as you want. Here is the [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-screen/nlipoenfbbikpbjkfpfillcgkoblgpmj?hl=en).

You can click on capture entire page option as here in the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this free [Screen Capture tool at CtrlQ.org](https://screenshot.guru/).
You just need to put the url of the page of which you want to take the screenshot.

For example, Here is a [screenshot of your question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzJRQ.png)